# Advanced Pandas: How to apply NOTNULL in pandas chaining?

Tags: python, pandas

I was doing some data manipulation with TMDB dataset and encountered the following problem.

Let's say I have a dataframe given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'rank': [1,2,3],
                 'belongs': [ "{'id': 1, 'name': 'Toy Story'}",
                              "{'id': 3, 'name': 'Grumpy Old Men'}",
                             np.nan
                            ]})

print(df[df.belongs.notnull()])
```

When I run the commands sequentially, I got the required franchise name:

```
fran = df['belongs'].copy()
fran = fran[fran.notnull()]
fran = fran.apply(ast.literal_eval)
fran = fran.apply(lambda x: x['name'] if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
fran = fran[fran.notnull()]

fran

0         Toy Story
1    Grumpy Old Men
```

How to chain these commands in an one-liner ?

I tried this:

```
(df['belongs'].copy()
.apply( lambda x: x[x.notnull()])
.apply(ast.literal_eval)
.apply(lambda x: x['name'] if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
.apply( lambda x: x[x.notnull()])
)
```

Gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'notnull'
```

I tried changing x to pd.Series(x) but some errors are persistent.

**How to chain the given operations?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain in one line

```
df['belongs'].copy().loc[lambda x : x.notnull()].apply(ast.literal_eval).\
      apply(lambda x: x['name'] if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
Out[205]: 
0         Toy Story
1    Grumpy Old Men
Name: belongs, dtype: object
```

---

For specific drop nan

```
 df['belongs'].copy().dropna()
```